# MySQL 5.5 SIGNAL and PDO exceptions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a TRIGGER for a MySQL table which raises exception with SIGNAL when there's something wrong with the data provided. How can I catch this exception in PHP with PDO?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

More information on my problem: I am executing several queries within a transaction and I want to rollback the transaction if one of them fails because there was a SIGNAL. Currently a signal is activated but all the other queries are executed.

ANOTHER UPDATE

So far I've got:

```
try {
  $db->beginTransaction();

  if (!$db->query('UPDATE accounts SET amount = amount - 10 WHERE id = 1')) {
    throw new Exception($db->errorInfo()[2]);
  }

  if (!$db->query('UPDATE accounts SET amount = amount + 10 WHERE id = 2')) {
    throw new Exception($db->errorInfo()[2]);
  }

  $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $db->rollback();
  echo 'There was an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Is this the proper way to do a transaction with handling the exceptions?
Sorry if my question is too broad.

Comment: That is also possible. You are generating your own exceptions. However, you are missing out on the detailed error message. The procedural way in my solution example code also does the same thing and more or less have the same logic flow.

Comment: I also do not see $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE) which is mandatory requirement for managing transactions. Ensure you have it on top.

Comment: The PDO manual says beginTransaction() turns autocommit off. Or am I mistaking?

Comment: :) No you are perfectly right! I somehow had it in my mind as mysqli and not PDO. Here is the link and confirmation. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$ls_error = "";
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
// first sql
if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
    $ls_error .= sprintf("Error: %d: %s\n",$mysqli->errno,  $mysqli->error);
    $mysqli->rollback();
}
// second one
if ($ls_error == "") {
    if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
        $ls_error .= sprintf("Error: %d: %s\n",$mysqli->errno,  $mysqli->error);
        $mysqli->rollback();
    }
}

// third one
if ($ls_error == "") {
    if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
        $ls_error .= sprintf("Error: %d: %s\n",$mysqli->errno,  $mysqli->error);
        $mysqli->rollback();
    }
}
if ($ls_error == "") {
    $mysqli->commit();
} else {
    echo $ls_error;
}
```

Comment: So MySQL signals aren't automatically converted to exceptions in PHP and for each query in the transaction I have to manually check if it was successful. Is that correct?

Comment: That is true. PHP is just a language connecting to MySQL. Its MySQL database handling functions are checking for an error and issuing a rollback to the database. This is needed as you have disabled autocommit to ensure you manage the transactions yourself. As such, if successful at the end you issue a Commit or else the rollbacks have already been issued.

Comment: I've updated my question with a code sample. It will be much appreciated if you can give me an advice if this is the right way to implement it.

Comment: My answer is not useful but the best answer? :) Tx!

Answer (score 0):

Abstract example. I have the solution works without any problems.

Trigger:

```
IF NEW.value < 0 THEN
  SET @msg = CONCAT('Wrong count_from value! ', NEW.value);
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'HY000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
END IF;
```

php (PDO):

```
try {
  $conn->query('INSERT INTO `table` SET `value` = -1');
} catch (Exception $err) {
  $error_message = $conn->query('SELECT @msg')->fetchColumn();
}
```